# In Angular version 4 I get a factory error when doing an ng build

Tags: angular, webpack

In Angular version 4 I get a factory error when doing an **ng build**.

When I do an **ng serve** that works fine.

My guess is something wrong with the @ngx-meta/core.
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-meta/core)

I don't understand the iTerm build error.

**This is my iTerm error:**

[image]

**This is my main.ts:**

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**This is my app.module:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { MetaModule } from '@ngx-meta/core';

//App
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

//Pages
import { HomeModule } from './components/home/home.module';

//Shared
import { HeaderModule } from './components/shared/header/header.module';
import { FooterModule } from './components/shared/footer/footer.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HeaderModule,
    FooterModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    MetaModule.forRoot(),
    HomeModule,
    PageNotFoundModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is my home component route:

```
import { Route} from '@angular/router';
import { MetaGuard } from '@ngx-meta/core';

import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

export const HomeRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [MetaGuard],
    component: HomeComponent,
    data : {
      meta: {
        title : 'Title',
      }
    }
  }
];
```

Comment: What is the angular cli version?

Comment: "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0",

Comment: Update angular cli to 1.2.4 , and zone to 0.8.14.

Comment: I've just updated it to version:  "@angular/cli": "^1.6.4", and it worked, thanks